# Access points with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, linestring

I have a PostGIS table with linestring geometries and point (A) on it and I need to detrimine points (M) which located M meters from A. Distance is measured along linestrings. Any thoughts?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pgRouting driving_distance(). If your point A is a node in the network, it's easy. Otherwise you'll probably have to introduce a temporary node.

An [example using pgRouting](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/) 100 km around a node:

[image]